# How should class members that may not be used be treated to optimize for performance, uninitialized or initialized to some default value?

Tags: java, c++, oop

Let's say I have a class `Test`.

```
class Test{
        string testNum, description;
    public:
        Test(string num); // A constructor that only sets testNum = num
};
```

`Test` is a class that stores tests I administer. `testNum` is the number of the test, the `description` is an optional string that describes the test.

Since `description` is optional, sometimes I will include it in `Test` objects, sometimes I won't.

In the constructor shown above where a description is not passed to the constructor, is it better practice to leave `description` uninitialized or initialize it to some default value (e.g. "NO DESCRIPTION") in the constructor?

**More importantly, if `description` is initialized to a default value, will that affect program performance (e.g. by taking up unnecessary memory or increasing runtime), or is the effect negligible?**

I am using C++ (if that affects potential answers), but this can be answered for OOP in general.

Comment: If in some cases there is no description, then you'd best leave it empty. Note that the default constructor of std::string will be called. Initializing to "NO DESCRIPTION" may potentially cause dynamic allocations which may slow down your performance.

Comment: In terms of Java, fields that are objects are initialized to `null` if you do not initialize them yourself. If I am declaring a default constructor, I often provide default values in order to avoid issues with `null` while using the class later on.

Comment: In Java, you can't leave it uninitialized, because it is automatically initialized to `null`. If you don't want `null` for undefined description, you can explicitly initialize it to an empty string, i.e. `""`, or since it is optional, as you said yourself, you could make it an `Optional<String>` and make the value `empty()`. Whether you want `null`, `""`, `empty()`, or some other default value is entirely opinion-based, so I'm **voting to close this question as "primarily opinion-based"**.

Comment: As stated in "Optional - The Mother of All Bikesheds" by Stuart Marks (https://youtu.be/Ej0sss6cq14), one should try to refrain from using `Optional` as a field. One example given is using `Optional` as a return type in a search method, where `null` might normally be returned if the target wasn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Best Practices

I think that general OOP wisdom would say:

- Avoid optional fields when possible, since they may indicate a weakness in your object model.
- When optional fields are present, prefer initializing them to a default value over leaving them uninitialized - it's one less random thing to worry about during debugging.

In the case of something like `description`, my initial response is that you could probably get away with making it required - it sounds like a field that is only optional because you don't want to obligate someone to always come up with a description when they're in the middle of thinking about other things, even though it would probably make life easier in the long run if everything had a description.

### Performance Impact

Initializing a value like `description` to a default value will carry some small cost - the exact cost will depend on the value to which it's being set and various aspects of your target platform. In most cases, the cost will probably be negligible; the best way to tell if the cost is meaningful or not is to use a profiler or similar tool to analyze where your program spends most of its time. [As Donald Knuth wrote](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization):

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.